# handlebars expression not working

Tags: javascript, django, handlebars.js, expression, chatbot

I'm building a chatbot UI using Handlebars and Django. The `{{}}` expression is not working in html while the `console.log` shows that my javascript is returning values. This is my code. Please help with this code?

handlebars template in html:

```
script id="message-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<li class="clearfix">
    <div class='message-data align-right'>
    <span class='message-data-time' > {{time}}, Today </span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="message-data-name" >You</span> <span class="fa fa-circle me"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="message other-message float-right">
    {{messageOutput}}
    </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

Screenshots attached below :-
[evaluated variable from console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLjJc.png)
[chrome console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k75gp.png)

[html error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0skmW.png)
[html error message 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9YeL.png)

Comment: What do you mean by not working in html ? Nothing is displayed or are the tags displayed without beeing changed ?

Comment: Hi Christophe, thanks for replying. The chat box is supposed to show the question and answers entered but in my case nothing is displayed.

Comment: Hi Christophe, I attached the screen cap of the chrome console log. it seems that my handlebars template was rendered without a value inside.

Comment: It seems like something has parsed out the {{}} before handlebars even has a chance to process them.

Comment: It seems that your template is well processed by Handlebars, the {{}} mustaches dissapear because Handlebar don't find the appropriate properties in your data : {{time}} and {{messageOutput}} are missing. Try to print {{this}} in order to display your data.

Comment: Try to use this in your template : {{#each this}}Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}}{{/each}} with this you'll iterate over your data properties and see what are your real data that are passed to the template.

Comment: Hi Christophe, I have tried to apply your fix by adding {{#each this}}
   {{messageOutput}}
   {{this}}{{/each}} in my code. but got error, I have attached the screenshot of the error page above. Actually, I don't need to iterate in my JSON data as there are only two elements inside: response and time and each element has only one value. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you change what I wrote, this is not a fix but something to help you debugging write it as it is : {{#each this}}Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}}{{/each}} Then put you html result here

Comment: Hi Christophe, I have applied the exactly the same code in my html but still got the same error message: "Could not parse the remainder: '#each this' from '#each this'". Sorry, I'm very new to handlebars

Comment: Do you have a codepen or something like that to show me the code that you use ?

Comment: I don't have codepen, but I will create one and paste the link here for your reference.

Comment: Hi Christophe, here is the link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/CookieLei/pen/OweMep

Comment: Hi Christophe, I've solved the issue. It's because of Django and handlebars use the same tag. So after I've added {% verbatim %} {{messageOutput}} {% endverbatim %}, it works now.

Comment: Nice have a good day, you can answer your own question now

Comment: Hi Christophe, thanks for the help though.